# dynamic link to sub page meta description

Tags: html

I am new to web page development. Something I would like to do, is create a link to a sub-page, and have the text part of the link display the meta description of the sub-page dynamically. So if at some point I update the description of the sub page, then refresh the browser on the main page, that updated description will display automatically in the link. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Wheres the description of the sub-page coming from?

Comment: Did you see my answer? was it useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need php for this. Something like

```
<?php
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.yousite.com/');
$content = $tags['description'];
echo "<a href=\"http://www.yousite.com/\">".$content."</a>";
?>
```

Comment: thanks Sergio. This was useful. To get this to work, I had to install the PHP script interpreter onto my test server. It turned out to not be too difficult. Then I learned I can only test these PHP pages on the server. Finally it turns out the simplified version of what you provided worked very well:

Comment: <?php $tags= get_meta_tags('2008-Present_SPI/index.html');echo $tags['description'];?>